# deploy grails / java 8 compiled war to tomcat 7 / JVM 7?

Tags: tomcat, grails

Searching on the internet suggests that the above info message in the catalina.out log is not fatal when deploying an application. It is caused by tomcat having already loaded the jar.

But this is the background and the reason for the frustration (on my part).

I have a grails 3 REST app. I changed the logback file so that it debugs to a file. It works in development and the log file is created. And curl works as expected. Grails is set to use java 8.

I create a war (grails war) and deploy it to tomcat 7. The deployment works but there are messages in the catalina.out log

```
Nov 20, 2016 9:42:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/heroes.war
Nov 20, 2016 9:42:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/heroes/WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Nov 20, 2016 9:43:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/heroes.war has finished in 14,256 ms
```

But there is no DEBUG logfile created. And curl is not receiving anything (requested resource is unavailable).

I do have a grails 3 (using java 7) war that does work as expected in this tomcat.

So any ideas as to what else to investigate? And is this a java 8 / tomcat 7 problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I rebuilt the war with java 1.7 and deployed it to tomcat 7 and even though I still got the validateJarFile message, rest now works.

So it does make a difference and need to upgrade to tomcat 8